# exposure or read specific data from firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am a new programmer using the Android Studio
I want to build an application that records  data by a person when he click on the button .

but find some problems

what i did to now

```
   private static final int GALLREQ = 1;
    private EditText name1,name2,name3,name4,name5,name6,name7,name8,name9,name10,name11;
    private StorageReference storageReference = null;
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    private Button button;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        name1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1N);
        name2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextNu);
        name3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextT);
        name4 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        name5 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        name6 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText5);
        name7 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText7);
        name8 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText8);
        name9 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText9);
        name10 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText10);
        name11 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText11);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);



        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Item");


        storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("Item");

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    }

    public void Ait(View view) {
        final String name_text = name1.getText().toString().trim();
        final String phone_text = name2.getText().toString().trim();
        final String altalp_text = name3.getText().toString().trim();
        final String ma_text = name4.getText().toString().trim();
        final String ma1_text = name5.getText().toString().trim();
        final String ma2_text = name6.getText().toString().trim();
        final String ma3_text = name7.getText().toString().trim();
        final String ma4_text = name8.getText().toString().trim();
        final String ma5_text = name9.getText().toString().trim();
        final String ma6_text = name10.getText().toString().trim();
        final String ma7_text = name11.getText().toString().trim();

        final DatabaseReference newpost = databaseReference.push();
        newpost.child("name").setValue(name_text);
        newpost.child("phone").setValue(phone_text);
        newpost.child("altalp").setValue(altalp_text);
        newpost.child("ma_text").setValue(ma_text);
        newpost.child("ma1_text").setValue(ma1_text);
        newpost.child("ma2_text").setValue(ma2_text);
        newpost.child("ma3_text").setValue(ma3_text);
        newpost.child("ma4_text").setValue(ma4_text);
        newpost.child("ma5_text").setValue(ma5_text);
        newpost.child("ma6_text").setValue(ma6_text);
        newpost.child("ma7_text").setValue(ma7_text);

    }
}
```

now i send my data to fire base .. i want when im looking for data about someone i can find it by the name or by the phone number and exposure in list view or in any thing ...?

**i hope my idea is clear for help ..?**

Comment: Are you getting a specific error? How does it not work?

Comment: no error ... i dont know how to implementation the idea Programmatically